# Get number from string

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the enclosed number between two slashes in a URL using regex. The code regex I have is not working, I am fairly new to regex and don't really understand it.

The regex:

```
http:\/\/?www\.?example\.com\/g\/(^\d$)\/\w
```

The URL:

```
http://www.example.com/g/1337/Game-Title
```

Trying to get the "1337", which is the PlaceId. The http:// and www. are optional

Comment: Which language are you using these regexes in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\d+` to match one or more digits.

```
\b(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?example\.com\/g\/(\d+)\/\w
```

put `http://` and `www.` inside a capturing or non-caturing group and then make it as optional by adding `?` quantifier next to that group. For both `http` and `https`, it would be `(?:https?:\/\/)?`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bB6lH1/1)

Comment: That got it partially working, but I want to to work without http;// OR www. being there.

Comment: In addition, the `\w` should probably be `\w+` or `[aA-zZ0-9_\-]+`

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard he just want to capture that particular digit only, so no prob..

Comment: @AdamS. ya, both are optional.

Comment: True. But then he is no longer using the regex for validation. You could leave out the http/www checking, too, in that case: `example\.com\/g\/(\d+)`. What I'm saying is: consistency is key.

Comment: `^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?example\.com\/g\/(\d+)\/[-\w]+$`